# PowerShell get-help don't see synopsis and other things

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am running PS2.0 on Win8.

When I run "get-help Get-ChildItem", I only see NAME and SYNTAX, where is the SYNOPSIS, RELATED LINKS and other info?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 8 comes with PS3.0 built-in, where you can use `Update-Help` (run as administrator) to update your help files.

If you are not on W8 and just have PS2.0 as you say and tagged, you can download the core help files from Microsoft [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10552)

Answer (score -1):

Try running `Update-Help`. That should pull in the full help for all modules ( and run the console as administrator)

Answer (score -2):

Update-Help run as administrator solved the issue for me (powershell 5.1 and 7).
SYNOPSIS, RELATED LINKS started to show.

Comment: how is this different from the other Answer that uses `Update-Help`?